# Simple "Hello World" style program closes extremely soon after execution starts

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013

I am learning C++ through a book called *C++ A Beginners Guide Second Edition*. When I run the executable, It displays it for half a second and closes it.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on Windows 8.1.

Here is the code:

```
*/
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "C++ is power programming.";

    return 0;

}
```

I can only just see the text when I run, as the console closes so quickly.

Why does the program close so fast, and how do I stop that from happening?

```
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Benjamin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[6908] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Perhaps add the line [code]system('pause')[\code] before [code]return[\code]

Comment: Google for "how do I pause after execution VS2013" - there's an IDE setting. If you ran your program as-is from the cmd line, your output would stay visible.

Comment: "why does it close after 0.5 seconds"?

Comment: Press CTRL + F5 to start the program.

Comment: If this helps, this is the output:

Comment: @user3650216 It closes because it's done what you asked. i.e. `cout << "C++ is power programming.";`, after that, the program closes because the end of main has been reached. You can stop this by adding something like `cin.get()` just before the return statement.

Comment: run from the console for the output to stay visible.

Comment: @OMGtechy Thanks, I'll start using this site more now, first question here! It worked perfectly, and I am amazed by the responses. Is there a way to mark up your comment or like it?

Comment: @user3650216 If you'd like, I could write it up in an answer for you?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going through your program line by line:

```
int main()
{
```

This defines the entry point for your program, and the `int` that it returns will be returned to whatever started the program.

```
    std::cout << "C++ is power programming."; // or just cout when you're using namespace std
```

This prints the string literal `C++ is power programming.` to the console.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Returning a value of 0 to the caller is often used to indicate success (the program executed successfully). You could however, return something else if you wanted to (for example, if your program computes some value that should be used by the caller).

So, in a nutshell, you tell your program to print a message to the console and then return, which is exactly what it does. If you wanted to stop the program from closing as soon as it's finished, you could something just before the `return 0` statement like this:

```
std::cin.get(); // or just cin.get() when using namespace std
return 0;
```

What `std::cin.get()` does is wait for user input; pressing enter should end your program when you're ready.

Answer (score 3):

It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  It displays the text and then the program exits.

When the program exits, standard windows behavior is to close the windows.

As such, lots of people in this stage of development add a `sleep(5)` to the end, or simply read a character from the user.

There is also a setting in the preference to disable this behavior.

there is a great writeup on solutions here : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7312/ , but perhaps one of the easiest solution is to create a function like this:

```
void PressEnterToContinue()
{
     std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue... " << flush;
     std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits <std::streamsize> ::max(), '\n' );
}
```

And call it right before exitting `main`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer, I had an easier solution but no doubt I will try this as well.

Comment: Doesn't work, however don't bother trying for a new answer - I have one -v-

Comment: Then you should post it! :)

Comment: Someone else posted it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should request user input at the **end of *main*** (before *return*) to hold the window on screen, until a character/key is pressed as in:

```
char c;
scanf("press a key: %c", &c);
```

or

```
char c = getchar();
```

or

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
```